# truncate text using linq

Tags: c#, linq

Looking for a simple query to truncate text by x amount of characters using Linq.

Comment: Please give more details. It's not at all clear what sort of truncation you're looking for, or what relation it has to LINQ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a pretty simple combination of `Select` and `Substring` to truncate the strings to a certain length:

```
var words = new List<string>();

// fill the list of words

var truncated = words.Select(w => w.Substring(0, 15));
```

Answer (score 7):

Your question is unclear. Based on your comment to [Justin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3863797/truncate-text-using-linq/3863826#3863826) it sounds like the simpler way to achieve what you're describing would be as follows:

```
string input = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog";
string result = new String(input.Take(15).ToArray());
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Notice that there is no need to call `ToCharArray()` since a string implements `IEnumerable<char>`. IntelliSense in VS2008 does not show up but the extension methods still work. Likewise, you can use the string constructor and pass it an array of characters instead of using `Aggregate`.